# why does webclient not download on second call VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, webclient

```
Public Sub downloadFile(ByVal url As String)
        LogFile.displayMessage("add url=" & url)
        downloadURLs.Enqueue(url)

        If t Is Nothing Then
            LogFile.displayMessage("create new thread")
            t = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadedDownloadFile)
        End If

        If Not t.IsAlive Then
            LogFile.displayMessage("start thread")
            t.Start()
        End If

    End Sub


 Private Sub download()
        LogFile.displayMessage("thread running count=" & downloadURLs.Count)
        If downloadURLs.Count > 0 Then
            Dim client = New WebClient()
            AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf downloadFileCompleted
            AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf downloadProgressChanged

            Dim url = downloadURLs.Dequeue()
            LogFile.displayMessage("downloading url=" & url)
            url = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
            Dim fileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)

            progress = 0
            LogFile.displayMessage("downloading NOW NOW NOW url=" & url)
            client.DownloadFile(New Uri(url), localAddress & fileName)
        End If
        LogFile.displayMessage("thread end")
    End Sub
    Private Sub downloadFileCompleted() 'ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
        LogFile.displayMessage("download complete ") ' & e.Result)

        LogFile.displayMessage("set next download going")
        download()
    End Sub
```

but on the second round it gets the url and then stops at the downloadfile.
it does this with `downloadfileasync` also.

i have seen many webpages discussing this, but none that fix it

does anyone know how this can be fixed?

ADDITIONAL details

i do start a new thread, but no matter how i do it, the webclient.downloadfile or downloadfileasync etc.
they all seem to work great the first time but then on second call, they do seem to download as a file appears, but the progress call is never made, and it never returns to complete.

I have tried dispose, then nothing it, then redeclare it, and even force garbage collect after dispose, nothing.

but it still does not want to work.

I am exploring doing the transfer myself, via streams

Comment: sorry about layout i couldn't get the code tags to work, if some can explain how they work i will fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was nothing to do with the download, it was this code:-

Dim wrequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim wresponce = wrequest.GetResponse()

```
    'save new url to be returned
    return wresponce.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
```

I now call close and null the instances after there use.

`'making sure to close off unneeded resources after use
        wresponce.Close()
        wresponce = Nothing
        wrequest = Nothing`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the thread is still active as you don't check for that condition.

Try changing your code as follows to test my theory:

```
If Not t.IsAlive Then
    LogFile.displayMessage("start thread")
    t.Start()
else
    LogFile.DisplayMessage("Thread was still active")
End If
```

I would have thought you would want to start a new thread each time anyway?